# postgres TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, typeerror, psycopg2

```
cursor = self.conn.cursor()  
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO "+self.db_name+" (name,sku,description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (sku) DO UPDATE SET name = %s ,description = %s",(self.file.values.tolist(),self.file.values.tolist()[1],self.file.values.tolist()[2]))
       self.conn.commit()
```

Getting error :

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Changed the code and tried :

```
 cursor = self.conn.cursor()  
 cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO "+self.db_name+" (name,sku,description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (sku) DO UPDATE SET name = VALUES (name) ,description = VALUES (description)",self.file.values.tolist())
        self.conn.commit()
```

Getting error :

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ....') ON CONFLICT (sku) DO UPDATE SET name = VALUES (name) ,de...
```

How to send values for `conditional statements....VALUES(name)` works in `mysql` but not in `postgres`.
Please help me on this?

Comment: You need to spend some time here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and here [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) and here [SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). As to syntax error, that is not a correct `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: For `UPDATE` syntax see here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).